# 3 or more foreign in pivot in laravel

Tags: database, laravel-5, relationship

How can I use `attach()` if I have 3 foreign fields in my `pivot` table.

`user_id`
`car_id` 
`country_id`

I tried to use;

`User` Model

`belongsToMany('Car', 'carcountry_user', 'user_id', 'car_id');`

`belongsToMany('Country', 'carcountry_user', 'user_id', 'country_id');`

`MyController`

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->cars()->attach(1);
$user->countries()->attach(2);
```

Those 2 (1, 2) `IDs` are exists in my database. But it returns an error;

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: I would reconsider using a 3 way pivot table to be honest. They can be better defined by separate belongs to many relationships. In your case, a country has many users, whom in turn potentially have many cars. Therefore, you can use has many and belongs to many though to establish country to cars and cars to country relationships.

Comment: @btl alright. Maybe I should just use `eager loading`...